# Looping through matches in file and performing arithmetic on field after match

Tags: loops, awk

I have a file with 100s of occurrences similar to the following lines:

```
   X201
   99.12c   9.8360E-05
   120.50c  1.0550E-05
   145.99c  2.7650E-05
   X202
   89.12c   2.8360E-05
   120.50c  8.7550E-05
   345.99c  5.6650E-05
```

I need to replace every occurrence of `120.50c` with the value of the field immediately after multiplied by a certain fraction.  So for the first occurrence of matching `120.50c`, I need to multiply the field `1.0550E-05` by 0.79, 0.10, and 0.11.

So for the match of `120.50c` between `X201` and `X202` which is `120.50c  1.0550E-05`, I need the entire line replaced with the following three lines:

```
   120.39c  8.3345E-06
   120.40c  1.0550E-06
   120.41c  1.1605E-06
```

The `120.39c,` `120.40c`, and `120.41c` would be strings I specify which would be done for each match of `120.50c`.  Because the value after each `120.50c` is different, I can't do a simple find and replace.

After running the script I'd like to end up with the following output.

```
   X201
   99.12c   9.8360E-05
   120.39c  8.3345E-06
   120.40c  1.0550E-06
   120.41c  1.1605E-06
   145.99c  2.7650E-05
   X202
   89.12c   2.8360E-05
   120.39c  6.9165E-05
   120.40c  8.7550E-06
   120.41c  9.6305E-06
   345.99c  5.6650E-05
```

I've been battling it out with awk and can't get it to work.  I'm thinking I may need to use Perl or Python instead.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the poor editing.  This is my first question although I've found stack overflow as a great resource constantly.  I'm searching on 120.50c and want the line replaced with the value following 120.50c multiplied by 0.79, 0.10, and 0.11.  So what I want to end up with is

Comment: where do `120.39c, 120.40c, 120.41c` come from?

Comment: They are the identifiers I want  `120.50c` replaced with.  So instead of `120.50c`, I want a line with `120.39c  8.3345E-06`. The `8.3345E-06` is the `1.055E-05` multiplied by 0.79.  The `120.40c` and `120.41c` would have values multiplied by 0.10 and 0.11, respectively.

Comment: @EdMorton No, they are just lines in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=split("0.79 0.10 0.11",coeff)} 
            {key="120.50c"; c=39; 
             if($1==key) 
               for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
                 {sub(50,c++,key); 
                  printf "%s\t%.4e\n", key, $2*coeff[i]; key=$1} 
             else print}' file | column -t
X201
99.12c   9.8360E-05
120.39c  8.3345e-06
120.40c  1.0550e-06
120.41c  1.1605e-06
145.99c  2.7650E-05
X202
89.12c   2.8360E-05
120.39c  6.9164e-05
120.40c  8.7550e-06
120.41c  9.6305e-06
345.99c  5.6650E-05
```

Comment: Thank you!  Works so much better than the hack script I was limping along.

Comment: This is the path I was going, your way is much cleaner.  `awk '/120.50c/{one=$2*0.79} {two=$2*0.10} {three=$2*0.11} {print} /120.50c/{printf "%s %8.5E\n %s %8.5E\n %s %8.5E\n","         129.39c", one, "        120.40c", two, "        120.41c", three}' $file | grep -v "120.50c" > output`